# Assigning JSON data to a variable or constant and doing string comparison - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I am new to AngularJS and started working on web unit testing using test cafe. My problem is in inspect element I have set of JSON data, which is generated when I pass few text in text field and click on search. I need to get this JSON data to a variable or constants for string comparison. JSON data is like:

```
value = {
    "CVLocation": "",
    "PostalCode": "",
    "DistanceInKms": "",
    "CVJobTitles": "java",
    "CVSkills": "",
    "CVIndustries": "",
    "CVLicenses": "",
    "CVWhiteBoard": "",
    "CVCustomQuery": "",
    "CVFilterDataList": [],
    "JobTitlesSearchedWithIn": 2,
    "SkillsSearchedWithIn": .......
}
```

Could anyone help me how can do string comparison with these JSON data?

[screenshot of my web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLXwE.png)

how can i get this JSON data which is generated in Element blog to my code?

Comment: not enough info/code to help. Can you show us what your trying that isn't working? can you provide the block of unit test code you're trying to get working?

Comment: I need to get thisJSON data to a variable or Constant from inspect element block.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify()` to convert your JSON to string for comparison i.e `var myJSONString = JSON.stringify(value);` in your case.

If you want to compare individual properties of your JSON, simply access them like :- `value.CVLocation` or `value.PostalCode`.

Comment: JSON is generated in background and I can see it in inspect element. I need to get this JSON data from inspect element blog to my code. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```js
object={
    "CVLocation": "",
    "PostalCode": "",
    "DistanceInKms": "",
    "CVJobTitles": "java",
    "CVSkills": "",
    "CVIndustries": "",
    "CVLicenses": "",
    "CVWhiteBoard": "",
    "CVCustomQuery": "",
    "CVFilterDataList": [],
    "JobTitlesSearchedWithIn": 2,
    "SkillsSearchedWithIn": ""
}

for(obj in object){
  if(object[obj]==="java")
  console.log(obj)
 }
```

We can traverse through the object like this and compare its values through keys of object like this.

 Hope it helps.

Updated Answer:

 Since you want to retrieve **value** attribute of input

```
//Using Vanilla JS
document.getElementById("<some-id>").getAttribute("value");

//Using Jquery
$('#some_id').attr('value')
```

But in your case ID is not known as for now nothing is known as seen in the image. So inspect element that input and right click on the element code to get the selectors as shown below and get the attribute value in your JS file and apply the code given above.

[image]

```
$(<the selector>).attr('value')
```

and use

Comment: If I am having this JSON data, this I could have tried. But the JSON data is generated in the background and I can only see it in inspect element since I don't have access to source code. Could you once check screen shot which I have added now and help me?

Comment: @JayDee Have updated the answer . Hope it Helps. Do let me know if any further assistance required

Comment: Sure. i I will try it and get back to you soon.